# Method should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit, laravel-9

Test example:

```
$mock = $this->mock(GetAll::class);
$mock->shouldReceive('setCustomersQueryParametersDto')
     ->once()
     ->with($customerDto)
     ->andReturnSelf();

$mock->shouldReceive('execute')->once()->andReturn(collect([])); 

$this->actingAs($user)->json('GET', $this->generateUrl());
```

How does it work? I have class GetAll and that class has a setter (setCustomersQueryParametersDto) before the **execute** method call, I need to set my DTO class which I did first. And then I expected when running the test, that everything should be fine, but in my controller response from execute method is wrong.

Code in controller:

```
$this->getAllAction->setCustomersQueryParametersDto($customersRequest->model())->execute();
```

Comment: You're creating feature tests not unit tests, these tests should run on live code (to test the flow of an endpoint, for example) instead of using unit mocks. Let it request to the endpoint and then test expectations based off the response, to check if a table has the new value you want, or the response body has the json you expected.

Comment: Okay, it is a request to do in that way. 
However, I am struggling to understand how to set the response for this method: **setCustomersQueryParametersDto($customersRequest->model())** because after setting that field I am calling execute method that should return data to controller. And every time when I mock that, I get error from title. (method should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve a problem that I had. It is still a mystery to me why Mockery can't execute previous code. But because I only need results from **execute** method, I find work around with this piece of code:

```
$getAllMock->shouldReceive('setCustomersQueryParametersDto->execute')
           ->andReturn($results);
```

(Chain methods in Mockery documentation: http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html)

So I didn't have to bother about fields in **GetAll::Class**, I simply returned results and that's it. But in this case, it works, in some more complex examples, I will probably need to set a field, so it will be tricky.....